# Catch CORS error

Tags: javascript, cors

I'm trying to load a CORS-disabled image, and get the error:

```
Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy.
```

I've tried catching the error [as follows](http://jsfiddle.net/wLyWZ/), but that obviously will not work.

How can I catch CORS errors after setting the `.src` property of an image?

Comment: Please post your code (at least the relevant parts) in your question, not on an external (unrelated) site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Use the `onError` event](http://jsfiddle.net/2xBvB/).

```
if(image.addEventListener) {
    image.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent error from getting thrown
        // Handle error here
    });
} else {
    // Old IE uses .attachEvent instead
    image.attachEvent('onerror', function (e) {
        // Handle error here
        return false; // Prevent propagation
    });
}
```

Code should probably be consolidated so you don't have to write your code twice, but hopefully you've got the idea.

Comment: Modern IE versions support [`addEventListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975245(v=vs.85).aspx). Only older versions require `attachEvent`.

Comment: More people use IE8 than IE9 Jonathan.

Comment: Of course, neither `addEventListener` nor `attachEvent` are neccessary if you are using a framework :-)

Comment: @AlienWebguy Actually, Microsoft auto-updated millions of instances of IE8 to IE9, and with the official release of Windows 8 and IE10, we'll see even more updates. Furthermore, IE10 will be released in less than a month to Windows 7 users. Tides are changing.

Comment: @JonathanSampson I'm aware. I was referring to something like `if(image.addEventListener) {} else{}`. I was just generalizing.

Comment: @JanDvorak Those frameworks use `addEventListener` and `attachEvent` internally ;) @Ktash, I understand. Feature-detection would be wise here for backward-compat.